# Breaking down html page with Preg-Match

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I currently get a html page containing data for the top ranking websites in Google, I need the ability to break down

```
<li class="g"><!--m--><div class="rc" data-hveid="74"><span class="altcts"></span><h3 class="r"><a href="http://airconditioning-london.co.uk/" onMouseDown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNH1BqTrwsbjky2ajPKpf01lUuU_JA','','0CEsQFjAB','','',event)"><em>Air Conditioning London</em> | Installation | Repairs | Maintenance |</a></h3><div class="s"><div><div class="f kv" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="vurls"><b>airconditioning</b>-<b>london</b>.co.uk/</cite>‎<div class="action-menu ab_ctl"><a class="clickable-dropdown-arrow ab_button" href="#" id="am-b1" aria-label="Result details" jsaction="ab.tdd;keydown:ab.hbke;keypress:ab.mskpe" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-ved="0CEwQ7B0wAQ"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span></a><div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" jsaction="keydown:ab.hdke;mouseover:ab.hdhne;mouseout:ab.hdhue" role="menu" tabindex="-1" data-ved="0CE0QqR8wAQ"><ul><li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4BhUc7PZJMgJ:airconditioning-london.co.uk/+&amp;cd=2&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=uk" onMouseDown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNHtODEWSJL7iUlNPyYez6IpTq8vUQ','','0CE4QIDAB','','',event)">Cached</a></li><li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="/search?pws=1&amp;igu=1&amp;gl=GB&amp;gll=53.41058,-2.97794&amp;near=london&amp;q=related:airconditioning-london.co.uk/+air+conditioning+london&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=jjj6UvCmBoyHrAe18oDwAQ&amp;ved=0CE8QHzAB">Similar</a></li></ul></div></div></div><div class="f slp"></div><span class="st"><em>Air Conditioning London</em>, We are London&#39;s best Cooling contractor. A specialist in Installation, Repairs, Service, Maintenance. Residential &amp; Commercial.</span></div></div></div><!--n--></li>
```

I need to be able to get the following information and I believe that PregMatch would be the best way to complete this;

< h3 > tag text - I need the text in between this tag
< h3 > tag link - I need to be able to get the URL from the link around the H3
< span class=st > tag text - I need to be able to get the text that shows in the span tag

I hope someone can help with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't use regular expressions to manipulate the DOM, use something like [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: preg_match is probably not ideal for this situation unless the data never changes. You're better off using a DOM parser.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have used http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm before so I will continue with that, I was under the impression PregMatch was better.

Answer (score 0):

## text in < h3 >

```
    $h3content = preg_replace('/<h3\b[^>]>(.*?)</h3>/', '$1', $source1);

    # link around the H3 < span class=st > ???
    # what you mean?

    # <span class="st"> text that shows in the span tag
    $spanContent = preg_replace('/<span\s+class="st"\b[^>]>(.*?)</span>/', '$1', $source1);
```